# Simplifying Additional Maths IGCSE Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi I have been struggling with simplifying this expression for 3 days, any help appreciated:

$\dfrac{(16p^4q^{-2})^{-3/2}}
{(25p^2q)^{-1/2}}
$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{2^{4\times-3/2}p^{4\times-3/2}q^3}{\frac15p^{-1}q^{-1/2}}=\frac{5q^{7/2}}{64p^5}.$$

Comment: The book says the answer is $\dfrac{5p-^5 q^{7/2}}
{64}
$   so still confused....

Comment: @Hancho They're the same.

Comment: Thank you, but I wondered why both of you chose to do it like that, and not how the book suggests...is there a rule I am missing?

Comment: @Hancho I've never studied what method is taught in IGCSE; there's only one right answer, but there are several ways to get it. I can only ensure what I did works.

Comment: @Hancho how the book suggests may not be the best way in practice. Use what you feel comfortable given that it give you good grades.

Answer (score 2):

$$= \dfrac{(25p^2q)^{1/2}}{(4^2p^4q^{-2})^{3/2}} = \dfrac{5pq^{1/2}}{4^3p^6q^{-3}} = \dfrac{5q^{7/2}}{64p^5}.$$

I deal with the +/- sign of the outmost power (1/2, 3/2) first.

Comment: The book says the answer is $\dfrac{5p-^5 q^{7/2}}
{64}
$   so still confused....

Comment: I move the $p^{-5}$ to the denominator. But yeah both J.G. and my ways both work.